# Factorial RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, oop, recursion, factorial

Newbie to Python have tried all the solutions i could think of need help Plz with this simple Recursion problem?

It works fine when the number is equal to zero.

```
class First:            #create Class
    def __init__(self,number):  #constructor
       self.number=number

    def factorial(reference,number):            #Problem within this Code

        if reference.number==0:
            return 1
        else:
            return (reference.number*reference.factorial(reference.number-1))

object1 = First(0)    #object creation
object1.number=int(input(["Enter The number For Factorial"]))
print("Factorial of a No is::",object1.factorial(object1.number))
```

> if reference.number==0: >
>
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: You're testing `reference.number`, not the function parameter `number` to decide wen to stop recursion. Change `if reference.number==0:` to `if number==0:`

Comment: you are always running the function with the same number `reference.number` and not the decremented argument `number`. Is there a specific reason you are creating a class here? because it is really not necessary and actually seems to just confuse you...

Comment: @Tomerikoo As i am new to python i just wanted to test recursion in Classes. Thank you for being helpful

Comment: @Aymal note that in addition to GPhilo's correction, you will also have to change the other uses of `reference.number` to just `number`. Actually, the only occurrence of `reference` inside the function should only be for the actual recursive call `reference.factorial`. Also, the python convention is using `self` to what you called `reference`. Finally, as you are new to Python, I would suggest practicing classes and recursion separately and only when you're comfortable with both, combine them